# removing an appended element using javascript/closure?

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-library

I currently have a click event in place that when selected appends a search box to .header, this is done using google closure. My problem now is if I click a close button I want to remove this appended element. I know using jQuery requires only .remove() but Im unsure how to achieve this in closure or vanilla js. Can anyone advise how I can do this?

Current code:

```
if(goog.dom.getElementsByClass('pe')){
    var searchCtn = goog.dom.getElementsByClass('search');     
    var headerWrapper = goog.dom.getElementByClass('header');     
    goog.dom.append(headerWrapper,searchCtn); 
} 

var closeButton = goog.dom.getElement('close');
    goog.events.listen(closeButton, goog.events.EventType.CLICK, function() {
    console.log('Remove appended');
}, false, this);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is this:

```
goog.dom.removeNode = function(node) {
  return node && node.parentNode ? node.parentNode.removeChild(node) : null;
};
```

So the code is like below(assume the search box is the parent of the close button):

```
goog.events.listen(closeButton, goog.events.EventType.CLICK, function() {
    goog.dom.removeNode(this.parentNode);
}, false, this);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, this.parentNode targets the parent of the close button, am i correct? how do i target the appended element if it isnt the close buttons parent?

Comment: @styler So just `goog.dom.removeNode(searchCtn);`

Answer (score 0):

Just use [element.removeChild(y)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150706025908/http://www.w3schools.com:80/dom/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_removechild)

```
$(function() {
  $('span').click(function() {    
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  });
});
```

That's jquery, but very easy to translate over to plain old javascript, or whatever framework you are in.